# Output table in slack slash command

Tags: web-services, slack-api, slack, tabular

I want slash command to output data in a table format?
I know that I will have to setup a custom integration for this. I did that using GET Method. [image]

I can setup my own web service on EC2 machine, but how should I make sure that data comes in table format.

May be something like this[image]
My problem is how should I make available data present in tabular format?

Answer (score 4):

It's unfortunately not possible to format Slack messages as a table in this way. You would need to resort to generating an image and referencing it in a message attachment. There is limited support for [displaying simple fields and labels](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#fields), but may not quite meet your needs.

Comment: if I resort to generate an image that contains in whatever format I want my data is, then probably this is the only method to push the image to slack
https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

Comment: Yes, though it might not display the way you'd like best that way. generating and hosting the image in your own infrastructure and loading the image by URL allows you better control of display without having to jump through too many hoops to get there.

Comment: @Guru have you found a solution to this question? There are bunch of libraries output'ing image of graphs but I haven't seen any for tabular. I appreciate you sharing your findings if there is any.

Comment: @cmertayak hey man. Though I searched only a day or two but I didn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. So We made a slack app and made it free for public. Please feel free to check it out. [https://rendreit.digital](https://rendreit.digital?utm_source=stackoverflow1)

After installing the app to your slack. You can do `/tableit` and paste in csv data or anything you copied from a spreadsheet (Excel or Google Sheet).

[image: Slash Command]
[image: Paste data]

It also let your preview the rendered table before you send it to the chat.

[image: Preview]
[image: Send]